# How do you show how to get this infinite series for sec?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\pi  \sec{\left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)} = 4  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  (-1)^k\frac{2k+1}{(2k+1)^2-x^2}
.
$$

Preferably avoiding complex analysis or zig-zag numbers. This is my missing link in understanding the 1/(4k+1) series. I can get the similar series for tan (by differentiating log(sin) but have become really stuck with this trying similar approaches and looking for trig identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the sum in the followings:

$S= 4\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}  (-1)^k\frac{2k+1}{(2k+1)^2-x^2}=2  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1-x}+2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1+x}$

Let $k=2m$ if $k$ even and $k=2m+1$ if $k$ odd so we get:

$S=2  \sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{4m+1-x}-2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4m+3-x}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{4m+1+x}-2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4m+3+x}$

Introduce the digamma function: $\psi(1+z)=-\gamma+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\big(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{z+k}\big)$

We have the followings:

$S=\frac{1}{2}\big(-\psi(\frac{x+1}{4})+\psi(\frac{x+3}{4})-\psi(\frac{-x+1}{4})+\psi(\frac{-x+3}{4})\big)$

Using the reflection formula of digamma function:

$\psi(1-z)-\psi(z)=\pi \cot(\pi z)$

We get:

$S=\frac{\pi}{2}\big(\cot(\frac{\pi}{4}(x+1))+\cot(\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x))\big)$

After simplifing the expression using trigonometric laws:

$S=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{2}{\cos(\frac{x\pi}{2})}=\pi \sec(x\frac{\pi}{2})$

The statement is proved.

Comment: This will do it and I will learn about digamma function. Also found a related question where putting a=2x is equivalent to my question.

Comment: I would have a nother solution but there is a heavy integration where I gave it up. The integral: $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{t^x-t^{-x}}{(1+t^2)}dt$. Tomorrow I will deal with it. Perhaps it will help you.

Comment: thanks. There are parts of the related question's answers I don't yet get so yours is the best answer for me so far. I'm trying to stick to elementary functions and real analysis.  I'm also wondering why I can't make a similar approach work to that of deriving the pi*tan(pi*x/2) series expansion which seems to come out comparatively easy by differentiating the log of sinx (using the infinite product formula for sinx)